# Nesting view controllers inside a storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, viewcontroller

I'm learning how to use storyboards for iOS development and I can't seem to figure out how to manage multiple views on the same screen.

I want to be able to control multiple elements on the same screen, for example a `UITableView` with an `UIImageView` next to it.

This means I need 3 `UIViewControllers`, 1 for the `UITableView`, 1 for the `UIImageView`, and one for the main view. But as far as I can tell storyboards only allow for 1 controller per view hierarchy screen. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**View Controller Containment** is the way to go. Have a look at Apple's documentation about it:

[**Creating Custom Container View Controllers**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

> Container view controllers are a critical part of iOS app design. They
>   allow you to decompose your app into smaller and simpler parts, each
>   controlled by a view controller dedicated to that task. Containers
>   allow these view controllers to work together to present a seamless
>   interface.

You can use it in storyboards as well by using a container view.

[image]

Useful tutorial: [**Storyboards With Custom Container View Controllers**](http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers)

Comment: Unfortunately the link to the tutorial is dead.